# How to parse expressions with the decremental operator (e.g. "c--")?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction

I am trying to make a web-app in JavaScript that converts arithmetic expressions to i486-compatible assembly. You can see it here:
http://flatassembler.000webhostapp.com/compiler.html
I have tried to make it able to deal with expressions that contain the incremental and decremental operators ("--" and "++"). Now it appears to correctly deal with expressions such as:
`c++`
However, in a response to an expression such as:
`c--`
the web-app responds with:
`Tokenizer error: Unable to assign the type to the operator '-' (whether it's unary or binary).`
The error message seems quite self-explanatory. Namely, I made the tokenizer assign to the "-" operator a type (unary or binary) and put the parentheses where they are needed, so that the parser can deal with the expressions such as:
`10 * -2`
And now, because of that, I am not able to implement the decremental operator. I've been thinking about this for days, and I can't decide what to even try. Do you have any ideas?
Please note that the web-app now correctly deals with the expressions such as:
`a - -b`

Comment: How do you distinguish between unary and binary `+` and make `c++` work? Do the same thing with `-`.

Comment: I don't distinguish between unary '+' and binary '+'.

Comment: You seem to. If I enter `+-5` it compiles and interprets correctly (unary +), whereas if I enter `2+-5` it also compiles and interprets correctly (binary +).

Comment: Nevermind, it appears to be a bug where if the first token is a `+` it treats it as a binary `0 + x` when converting to an S-expression. It doesn't handle unary `+` in general.

Comment: Your tokenizer is trying to be too clever. If it sees a "-", followed by another "-", it should produce a "--" token (and move the cursor after the second -). If it sees a "-" followed by anything else, it should produce a "-" token. It should not generate parentheses that aren't there or check whether a `-` has enough operands - that's the parser's job.

Comment: This question is purely about parsing arithmetic expressions. It should not be tagged with `x86` or `assembly`. The fact that it converts to x86 code has nothing to do with the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that this works in all existing languages (that I know of anyway) that have these operators, is that `--` is a single token. So when you see a `-`, you check whether the very next character is another `-`. If it is, you generate a `--` token (consuming both `-` characters). If it isn't, you generate a `-` token (leaving the next character in the buffer).

Then in the parser an l-expression, followed by `--` token becomes a postfix decrement expression and `--` followed by an l-expression becomes a prefix decrement expression. A `--` token in any other position is a syntax error.

This means that spaces between `-`s matter: `--x` is a prefix decrement (or a syntax error if the language doesn't allow prefix increment and decrement), `- -x` is a double negative that cancels out to just `x`.

I should also note that in languages where postfix increment/decrement is an expression, it evaluates to the original value of the operand, not the incremented value. So if `x` starts out as `5`, the value of `x++` should be 5 and afterwards the value of `x` should be `6`. So your current code does not actually correctly implement postfix `++` (or at least not in a way consistent with other languages). Also `x++ + y++` currently produces a syntax error, so it doesn't seem like it's really supported at all.